# How to replace characters in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

It is given:
A xml string contains substring like this:

```
N'<node action="i" s=""petya""></node>'
```

What I need to do, if the string contains double "" :

1. replace action=any char with action="u".
2. replace "" with ".

For example, the result:

```
N'<node action="u" s="petya"></node>'
```

Comment: Honestly, if you have a need to do any serious XML work, you should look into using a parser, rather than a brittle SQL Server query.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the parser cannot be used because of the string is a bad formatted xml in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LATE ANSWER - Just to present an alternative approach   (already +1 Luv)**

**Example**

```
Declare @S nvarchar(max) = N'<node action="i" s=""petya""></node>'

Select @S = replace(@S,sFrom,sTo)
 From ( values ( 'action="i"','action="u"')
              ,( 'action="a"','action="u"')
              ,( 'action="d"','action="u"')   -- Assuming a limited number of actions
              ,( '=""','="')                  -- Leading ""
              ,( '"">','">')                  -- Trailing ""
              ,( '"" ','" ')                  -- Trailing ""
      ) A(sFrom,sTo)


Select @S
```

**Returns**

```
<node action="u" s="petya"></node>
```

> **EDIT - For Multiple/Conditional Nodes**

```
Declare @S nvarchar(max) = N'<node action="i" n="0" s=""petya""></node> <node action="i" n="2" s="vasya"></node>' 

;with cte as (
Select A.RetSeq
      ,A.RetVal
      ,NewVal = case when patindex('%""[a-z,0-1]%""%',A.RetVal)=0 
                     then A.RetVal
                     else replace(stuff(A.RetVal,B.RetPos,len(B.RetVal),'u'),'""','"')
                     end
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'<','>') A
 Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](A.RetVal,'action="','" ') B
)
Select @S = Stuff((Select '<' +NewVal+'>' From cte Order By RetSeq For XML Path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'),1,0,'')

Select convert(xml,@S)
```

**Returns Valid XML**

```
<node action="u" n="0" s="petya" />
<node action="i" n="2" s="vasya" />
```

**The Table-Valued Function**

Tired of extracting string (left,right,charindex,patindex,etc) I modified a parse/split function to accept two non-like delimiters.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: Ok, but in case like this N'<node action="i" n="0" s=""petya""></node>
<node action="i" n="2" s="vasya"></node>'
the tag action will be in both records replaced with action="u", but it should be replaced only in the 1st record

Comment: @Oleg one moment for a fix

Comment: @Oleg See EDIT for multiple nodes

Answer (score 2):

Replace @String with your column name:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(100)=N'<node action="i" s=""petya""></node>'

SELECT CASE WHEN @string LIKE '%""%' THEN 
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@STRING,1,CHARINDEX('action="',@string,1)-1)+'action="u"'
        +SUBSTRING(@STRING,CHARINDEX('action="',@string,1)+10,LEN(@STRING)),'""','"') 
        ELSE @STRING END
```

Comment: Only one note: if I have a tag like action="xxxx" it replaces it as action="u"xxx"